# Async Axios data with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, axios, vue-component

I'm trying to load data from an axios call into a table on my page, but there's no data in the table with my current code. I'm assuming that the page elements are being rendered before the axios call finishes and therefore nothing is loading.

```
export default {
  components: {
    BaseTable
  },
  data() {
    return {
      table1: {
        title: "Scene Objects",
        columns: [...tableColumns],
        data: [],
        type: "hover"
      },
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/card/leveldata').then((data) => {
      this.table1.data = Object.values(data.data['Card Level Data']);
    });
  }
};
```

I've tried a lot of things to fix it, including using v-if to wait for the call to finish but I can't get anything to work. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

template:

```
<template>
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <card type="plain" title="Scene Preview">
      <!-- <div id="map" class="map">
      </div> -->
      <iframe id="panoramic" src="https://momento360.com/e/u/9a0d3bcfff454d74950b0f9b8ded7e43?utm_campaign=embed&utm_source=other&heading=80.77&pitch=-0.4&field-of-view=75&size=medium"></iframe>
    </card>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <card :title="table1.title">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <base-table :data="table1.data"
                      :columns="table1.columns"
                      thead-classes="text-primary">
          </base-table>
        </div>
      </card>
      <base-button type="primary">Preview</base-button>
      <base-button type="primary">Save</base-button>

    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

BaseTable component:

```
<template>
  <table class="table tablesorter" :class="tableClass">
    <thead :class="theadClasses">
    <tr>
      <slot name="columns">
        <th v-for="column in columns" :key="column">{{column}}</th>
      </slot>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody :class="tbodyClasses">
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in data" :key="index">
      <slot :row="item">
        <td v-for="(column, index) in columns"
            :key="index"
            v-if="hasValue(item, column)">
          {{itemValue(item, column)}}
        </td>
      </slot>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'base-table',
    props: {
      columns: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => [],
        description: "Table columns"
      },
      data: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => [],
        description: "Table data"
      },
      type: {
        type: String, // striped | hover
        default: "",
        description: "Whether table is striped or hover type"
      },
      theadClasses: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        description: "<thead> css classes"
      },
      tbodyClasses: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        description: "<tbody> css classes"
      }
    },
    computed: {
      tableClass() {
        return this.type && `table-${this.type}`;
      }
    },
    methods: {
      hasValue(item, column) {
        return item[column.toLowerCase()] !== "undefined";
      },
      itemValue(item, column) {
        return item[column.toLowerCase()];
      }
    }
  };
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

Comment: Please share your template and also the `BaseTable` component code so e can analyse.
in adition did you tried adding a `colnsole.log('this.table1.data', this.table1.data);` to ensure that your data are well initialized ?

Comment: Just updated the original post. The BaseTable code is from a GitHub repo and I added the template code. But yes, I printed the data after assigning it and it was initialized with the correct values. This is what led me to believe that the template is being rendered before the table data is assigned.

Comment: `this.$set(this.table1, 'data', Object.values(data.data['Card Level Data']))`.  Replacing the array removes the reactivity. `this.$set` will maintain that reactivity.

Comment: Just tried this solution, unfortunately the same thing is happening. No errors but nothing in the table.

Comment: Seems like a pretty complicated design.  I would try to temporarily remove some functionality in order to simplify what is happening, and then keep logging to confirm functions are returning what you are expecting as you add back in complexity.

Comment: I noticed that the table is actually generating the correct number of rows but there's no data in the cells of the table. Not sure if that provides any more insight into the problem, though.